# Crash reporting with Adobe Flex Mobile application

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have developed a Mobile application using flex. The app is live on Apple and Google play store. Some time users are facing crashing problem with the application.

I need to integrate a crash reporting mechanism with the next version of application. I searched for the same and found some solutions i.e. Testflight ANE and Crashlytics ANE.

But test flight don't support crash reporting for new application, i used the Crashlytics ANE but i faced a lots of issue while integrating it finally i could not get any kind of crash reporting with it.

Can you please suggest some other ANE or solution to achieve the crash reporting for Adobe flex mobile application.

Comment: I've used custom logging system before, but it seems not working when app actually crashes, or you need to try-catch the points you thing are possible to crash.. Would like to hear a better solution :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov: I have used try-catch block at all possible points of exception, apart this application use third party ANE's and uses high amount of memory, that can be causes of application crash and which can't be handled inside try catch block.

Comment: Google Play sometimes provides crash reports, though not sure if are very helpful. And I'm also not sure how this can be achieved as the app will actually crash, and your code, whatever it is, won't execute (log crash result).. Still I'm interested in finding some kind of a solution :)